# How to filter a document in document library based on file properties using caml query?

Tags: development, document-library, caml-query, properties

I need to filter several documents in document library based on file properties(Two managed metadata property)using CAML query. Please suggest me an idea to achieve this

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
query.Query = @"<Where><And>
              <Contains>
                  <FieldRef Name='" + MyTaxonomyFieldName + @"' />
                  <Value Type='Text'>" + tagName + @"</Value>
              </Contains>
              <Contains>
                  <FieldRef Name='" + MyTaxonomyFieldName2 + @"' />
                  <Value Type='Text'>" + tagName + @"</Value>
              </Contains>
            </And>
            </Where>";
```